# Is it OK to design and test a secure web app without SSL?

Tags: security, web-applications, ssl

I need to build a small web app that will ultimately need to be launched via SSL.

My question is, can I design and test it as if it was an ordinary application and only later add whatever is necessary to make it secure ? Or I have to test it over SSL right from the start.

Comment: Depends what exactly you're testing. You should be able to test most things without integrating the SSL.

Comment: @Jamie Wong: That sounds like an answer: please post it as an answer so it can be voted on properly.

Comment: @S. Lott. I have no experience doing this, but I have experience testing web apps, and I don't see why there would be conflict. I figured it was better to let someone with real experience answer

Comment: @Jamie Wong: What?  Your comment sounds like an answer.  Whether you have "no experience doing this" or lots of experience doing this, your comment sounds like an answer.  Please post answers as answers.  If it's a comment, it should clarify the question or respond to other comments, not answer the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll be fine waiting on the SSL while you develop your app.  Be careful not to hard-code any `http://` urls, and I don't think you'll run into any problems for the bulk of your development.  Just make sure you do plenty of testing after making the switch to the SSL before going live.

Answer (score 4):

You can test with non-SSL, but there  are a few things to watch out for. If you're loading images or components (like a CAPTCHA, for example) off third-party sites, you'll want to make sure you can call them over SSL. Sometimes a tracking pixel for web analytics software can cause pain here too.

Answer (score 3):

> My question is, can I design and test it as if it was an ordinary application and only later add whatever is necessary to make it secure ? Or I have to test it over SSL right from the start.

If by `whatever is necessary to make it secure` you mean `enable ssl` then sure, go for it.  But if making it secure requires other things such as authentication, authorization, role-based access and what-not, then no.  The conventional wisdom is to include security at all phases of development because you can't just "switch it on" at the end.  Most of the issues in implementing a secure system with a rich set of access controls won't occur to you unless you are actually testing the core functionality while restricted by those controls and also have the opportunity to test both the "happy path" and the "unhappy path" through the code.

Answer (score 2):

Besides http url's watch out for port numbers your https traffic will not be on port 80.

Answer (score 2):

Proxy all your requests through a non-https resource on your domain specially if you are using ajax calls. I ran into an issue (make AJAX calls from non-SSL page to a SSL URL) a while back.